# Create a Tab as Adaptive card and refresh the content programmatically

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I wanted to check if is it possible to create a Teams app same as Search Message extension using Adaptive card. When you select a search result, it then creates an Adaptive card as a tab and also refresh the content every time someone opens the tab.

The only concern for me here is that how will I connect the newly created tab(Adaptive card) to a bot so that I can refresh them? Any ideas, let me know.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of embedding web content in an IFrame, you can render Adaptive Cards to a tab. While the front end is rendered with Adaptive Cards, the backend is powered by a bot. The bot is responsible for accepting requests and responding appropriately with the Adaptive Card that is rendered.
We can invoke activity requests and sends information in tab with Adaptive Cards. tab/fetch is the first invoke request that your bot receives when a user opens an Adaptive Card tab. When your bot receives the request, it either sends a tab continue response or a tab auth response. The continue response includes an array for cards, which is rendered vertically to the tab in the order of the array.
*Tabs with Adaptive Cards are currently only supported as personal apps.*

Also refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/build-adaptive-card-tabs

Comment: I can follow the logic for Personal Tab as I can attach bot id in manifest for it. I was looking for the same functionality on Config Tab, when on Save you create a Tab as adaptive card and then connect it to the bot.  In Save function , I can only provide the url for the tab not the adaptive card. Here is the sample:  microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {  microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
suggestedDisplayName:name,
entityId: id,
contentUrl: baseUrl + `${id}`,
websiteUrl: baseUrl +  `${id}`,
      });
      saveEvent.notifySuccess();
    });

Comment: As mentioned in the doc( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/build-adaptive-card-tabs), Tabs with Adaptive Cards are currently only supported as personal apps. And a configurable page can be used as channel or group chat tab.

Comment: Hi @Prasad-MSFT, do you know if at some point in a near future the Tabs with Adaptive Cards will be supported also for team, etc apps and not only for personal apps?

Comment: There is no such timeline available as of now. Thanks!